# why does my explosion look like minecraft?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I've reached my stress limit. Can anyone please tell me what I need to tweek to stop my explosion looking weird and blocky PLEASE?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've upped the render from 128 to 400 samples and no difference, i've set high resolution for the smoke sim too. It's taken me 2 days just to get it to even show in the viewport, had no idea had to bake it....the smoke sim isn't very intuitive

Comment: I assume you have divisions set up pretty high, like 16 or 32?  Could you show us a picture of the smoke settings?

Comment: I think your color ramp is not doing what you think it's doing. It's only setting the color. Te get fine control, you might try to make an attribute node for density and using a color ramp with that (I like B-spline color ramps). You just have to set the minimum density a little lower.